# plink ssh command as a variable from txt file using python

Tags: python, text, ssh, command, subprocess

Ive got a question about using plink and sending command as a variable from external file.

**test.txt** has inside:

```
id -a user.name1\n; id -a user.name2\n; id -a user.name3\n;exit\n
```

This code doesn't work:

```
import subprocess
sshoutput = open("c:/sshoutput.txt", "w")
sshoutputerror = open("c:/sshoutputerror.txt", "w")
sshinput = open("C:/test.txt", "r").read()
ssh = subprocess.Popen("plink user.name@server -pw password",shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=sshoutput, stderr=sshoutputerror)
ssh.communicate(sshinput)
```

But if i change last line **sshinput** to **"id -a user.name1\n; id -a user.name2\n; id -a user.name3\n;exit\n"**

```
ssh.communicate("id -a user.name1\n; id -a user.name2\n; id -a user.name3\n;exit\n")
```

This is actually working, but i'd like to use commands from external file.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include the line inside quotes in **test.txt** file.

Like this :

```
 "id -a user.name1\n; id -a user.name2\n; id -a user.name3\n;exit\n"
```

And use readline() in the place of read () :

```
import subprocess
sshoutput = open("c:/sshoutput.txt", "w")
sshoutputerror = open("c:/sshoutputerror.txt", "w")
sshinput = open("C:/test.txt", "r").readline()
ssh = subprocess.Popen("plink user.name@server -pw password",shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=sshoutput, stderr=sshoutputerror)
ssh.communicate(sshinput)
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer.! its working! me stupido! :)